# ListView won't update xamarin

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

So I have this code:

**This is the whole SlidingTabFragment.cs**

```
public class SlidingTabsFragment : Fragment
{
    private SlidingTabScrollView mSlidingTabScrollView;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_sample, container, false);
    }

    public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        mSlidingTabScrollView = view.FindViewById<SlidingTabScrollView>(Resource.Id.sliding_tabs);
        mViewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.Adapter = new SamplePagerAdapter();
        mSlidingTabScrollView.ViewPager = mViewPager;
    }

    public class SamplePagerAdapter : PagerAdapter
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        List<string> mItems;
        private ArrayAdapter<string> adapter;

        public SamplePagerAdapter() : base()
        {
            items.Add("Élelmiszerek");
            items.Add("Receptek");
            items.Add("Recept hozzáadása");
            items.Add("Bevásárlólista");
            items.Add("Előzmények");

            return ;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }

        public override bool IsViewFromObject(View view, Java.Lang.Object obj)
        {
            return view == obj;
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
        {

            View view = LayoutInflater.From(container.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.pager_item, container, false);
            container.AddView(view);

            int pos = position + 1;
            //I'm using a scrollable menu, and if the user is on the first page than this runs. Moving the `if` somehow fixed my problem.
            if (pos == 1)
            {
            var autoCompleteOptions = new string[] { "Sajt", "Tej", "Kecske", "Barátnő", "piros", "alma" };
            ArrayAdapter autoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(container.Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line, autoCompleteOptions);
            AutoCompleteTextView mautoCompleteTextView = view.FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.autoCompleteTextView1);
            mautoCompleteTextView.Adapter = autoCompleteAdapter;

            ListView mListView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myListView);
            LoadData();
            mListView.ItemLongClick += MListView_ItemLongClick;
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(container.Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mItems);
            mListView.Adapter = adapter;

            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

                   mautoCompleteTextView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                   mListView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }

            return view;
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {

            mItems = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
            {
                mItems.Add("Élelmiszer"+ i);
            }
        }

        private void MListView_ItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mItems[e.Position]);
            mItems.RemoveAt(e.Position);
            adapter.Remove(adapter.GetItem(e.Position));
            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public string GetHeaderTitle(int position)
        {
            return items[position];
        }

        public override void DestroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Java.Lang.Object obj)
        {
            container.RemoveView((View)obj);
        }

    }
}
```

**This is the fragment_sample.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutTextColor"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  <App6.SlidingTabScrollView
      android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/viewpager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0px"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="@color/grey" />
</LinearLayout>
```

//I'm trying to reproduce the problem in a smaller project.

**Fixed**

And my problem is that the ListView is not updating. i know the Listview is changeing, because if I longclick an item in it I see in the name of the item in the output in visual studio(because of the Console.Writeline in the MListView_ItemLongClick). And if I longclick the same item again it will write out he next item, because the first I clicked got deleted, but the ListView is not refreshing, so it looks like it's still there.

Comment: Have you tried calling `NotifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter?

Comment: I see that everywhere "use _NotifyDataSetChanged_() on the adapter" but i did it in the second row from behind: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: But you are doing it on ItemLongClick, not after you have actually loaded and assigned the adapter.

Comment: so in your opinion where should i use the NotifyDataSetChanged() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And my problem is that the ListView is not updating. i know the Listview is changeing, because if I longclick an item in it I see in the name of the item in the output in visual studio(because of the Console.Writeline in the MListView_ItemLongClick).

You need to delete items of your adapter instead of removing items directly on original list, please modify your `MListView_ItemLongClick` like codes below:

```
private void MListView_ItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mItems[e.Position]);
    mItems.RemoveAt(e.Position);
    //remove the items directly from adapter
    adapter.Remove(adapter.GetItem(e.Position));
    adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It doesn't work where it should be, but i created a new blank app, with just the ListView, and the remove, and it works there, I think the problem in my code above is maybe the layout LayoutInflater, or bad use of the ViewGroup. If you could take a look at those, and give your opinion that would be great thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide the missing codes for variables in your codes?  For example: `nezet`, `viewGroup`. And obviously you are using `ViewPager`,  could you also provide the layout codes. A basic sample that can reproduce this issue can also help.

Comment: I have updated the code, and working on a small project, to reproduce the problem. If you need anything else just say thanks.

Comment: Moving the if a bit higher fixed my problem. the ListView is now updating properly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Then what is the point of creating the ArrayAdapter with a the underlying collection in the constructor if you aren't then able to update the underlying collection, but instead must modify the adapter itself?  If its purpose is only in populating the initial list than its intention is very vague.